# How can I get the max and the min value for a specific timeframe grouped by day from a timeseries data

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, duckdb

I am using DuckDB and want to process some time-series data that has the following format:

```
┌─────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────────┐
│     Timestamps      │  Open   │  High   │   Low   │  Close  │ Volume │ CustomDate │
│      timestamp      │ double  │ double  │ double  │ double  │ int32  │  varchar   │
├─────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┼────────────┤
│ 2006-04-11 12:00:00 │ 1.21245 │ 1.21275 │ 1.21235 │ 1.21275 │      0 │ 2006-04-11 │
│ 2006-04-11 12:05:00 │ 1.21275 │ 1.21275 │ 1.21225 │ 1.21235 │      0 │ 2006-04-11 │
│ 2006-04-11 12:10:00 │ 1.21235 │ 1.21235 │ 1.21205 │ 1.21225 │      0 │ 2006-04-11 │
│          ·          │     ·   │     ·   │     ·   │    ·    │      · │     ·      │
│          ·          │     ·   │     ·   │     ·   │    ·    │      · │     ·      │
│          ·          │     ·   │     ·   │     ·   │    ·    │      · │     ·      │
│ 2023-01-31 22:55:00 │ 1.08705 │  1.0873 │ 1.08705 │ 1.08725 │      0 │ 2023-01-31 │
│ 2023-01-31 23:00:00 │ 1.08725 │ 1.08735 │   1.087 │ 1.08705 │      0 │ 2023-01-31 │
│ 2023-01-31 23:05:00 │ 1.08705 │  1.0871 │ 1.08695 │  1.0871 │      0 │ 2023-01-31 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┘
```

I am looking for a "complex" SQL query that can accomplish the following:

- Select a specific time frame in a day (f.e. 10:25:00 - 13:40:00)
- In this timeframe I want to get the MAX value from f.e High and the MIN value from Low
- I also need the corresponding timestamps so that I know when the MAX and MIN values occurred
- I want the result grouped by day
- I want to further analyze and query the result

This is how the result should ideally look like:

```
    Day    | HighMAX |     HighMAXTime     |  LowMIN  |     LowMINTime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-01-29 | 1.07545 | 2023-01-29 04:10:00 |  1.0726  | 2023-01-29 18:05:00
2023-01-30 | 1.08465 | 2023-01-30 23:55:00 |  1.08015 | 2023-01-30 15:35:00
2023-01-31 ...
...
```

This is the SQL query I currently have:

```
WITH mySession AS (
    SELECT *, strftime(Timestamps, '%Y-%m-%d') AS CustomDate,
    FROM EURUSD, 
    WHERE (Timestamps BETWEEN CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 12:00:00')::timestamp AND CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 15:30:00')::timestamp)
),
getSpecificData AS (
  SELECT 
    CustomDate,
    MIN(Low) AS LowOfSession,
    MAX(High) AS HighOfSession
  FROM mySession
  GROUP BY CustomDate
  ORDER BY CustomDate DESC
)
SELECT * FROM getSpecificData;
```

Current result:

```
┌────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ CustomDate │ LowOfSession │ HighOfSession │
│  varchar   │    double    │    double     │
├────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┤
│ 2023-01-26 │      1.08505 │        1.0906 │
│ 2023-01-25 │       1.0874 │        1.0925 │
│ 2023-01-24 │       1.0835 │       1.08905 │
│     ·      │          ·   │           ·   │
│     ·      │          ·   │           ·   │
│     ·      │          ·   │           ·   │
│ 2006-04-13 │      1.20945 │       1.21175 │
│ 2006-04-12 │       1.2094 │       1.21145 │
│ 2006-04-11 │      1.21205 │       1.21415 │
└────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Currently I get the MIN Lows and MAX Highs but I don't know how to also retrieve the corresponding timestamps of these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by `inner join` your select with the `EURUSD` table to get Timestamps needed :

```
 WITH mySession AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM EURUSD
    WHERE (Timestamps BETWEEN CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 12:00:00')::timestamp AND CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 15:30:00')::timestamp)
),
getSpecificData AS (
  SELECT 
    CustomDate,
    MIN(Low) AS LowOfSession,
    MAX(High) AS HighOfSession
  FROM mySession
  GROUP BY CustomDate
  ORDER BY CustomDate DESC
),
getDetails As (
  select s.*, l.Timestamps as TimestampsOfLow, h.Timestamps as TimestampsOfHigh
  from getSpecificData as s
  inner join mySession as l on s.LowOfSession = l.low and s.CustomDate = l.CustomDate
  inner join mySession as h on s.HighOfSession = h.High and s.CustomDate = h.CustomDate
)
SELECT customdate, lowofsession, highofsession, max(timestampsoflow), max(TimestampsOfHigh) FROM getDetails
group by customdate, lowofsession, highofsession;
```

Comment: `2023-01-25 │ 1.0894  │ 1.09185 │ 2023-01-25 12:05:00 │ 2023-01-25 13:25:00
2023-01-24 │ 1.08705 │ 1.0889 │  2023-01-24 12:05:00 │ 2023-01-24 13:10:00
2023-01-24 │ 1.08705 │ 1.0889 │  2023-01-24 12:00:00 │ 2023-01-24 13:10:00
2023-01-23 │ 1.08475 │ 1.0873 │  2023-01-23 14:50:00 │ 2023-01-23 13:50:00`

I changed the first `SELECT *` to `SELECT *, strftime(Timestamps, '%Y-%m-%d') AS CustomDate,` and the inner join table to `inner join mySession` and the query works. But for a few days I do get multiple data and I don't know why.

Comment: I got it, I have made an update can you check

Comment: This is looking great!!! I only changed `max(timestampsoflow)` and `max(TimestampsOfHigh)` to `min` in order to get the first occurrence of the timestamps and it works great. I will analyze the data more in detail but at the first glance the result looks very good. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want the window functions first_value and last_value. ([DuckDB doc](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/window_functions.html))

```
WITH mySession AS (
        SELECT *, strftime(Timestamps, '%Y-%m-%d') AS CustomDate,
        FROM EURUSD, 
        WHERE (Timestamps BETWEEN CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 12:00:00')::timestamp AND CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 15:30:00')::timestamp)
    ),
    getSpecificData AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        CustomDate,
        FIRST_VALUE(timestamps) over (PARTITION BY CustomDate order by Low) as LowOfSession_timestamp,
        LAST_VALUE(timestamps) over (PARTITION BY CustomDate order by High) as HighOfSession_timestamp,
        FIRST_VALUE(Low) over (PARTITION BY CustomDate order by Low) as LowOfSession_value,
        LAST_VALUE(High) over (PARTITION BY CustomDate order by High) as HighOfSession_value,
      FROM mySession
      ORDER BY CustomDate DESC
    )
    SELECT * FROM getSpecificData;
```

Comment: `2023-01-31 │ 2023-01-31 12:10:00 │ 2023-01-31 13:45:00 │ 1.08505 │ 1.0875 │
2023-01-31 │ 2023-01-31 12:10:00 │ 2023-01-31 14:10:00 │ 1.08505 │ 1.0871 │
2023-01-31 │ 2023-01-31 12:10:00 │ 2023-01-31 13:35:00 │ 1.08505 │1.08725 │`

Not sure qhy, but I am getting different values for HighOfSession_timestamp and query is not grouped by a single day.

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE(timestamps) over (PARTITION BY CustomDate order by High DESC) as HighOfSession_timestamp`
When I switch LAST_VALUE to FIRST_VALUE but order partition with DESC for the timestamps and High column, I get the correct result. Do you maybe know why LAST_VALUE doesn't work like it should?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query

```
WITH mySession AS (
    SELECT *, strftime(Timestamps, '%Y-%m-%d') AS CustomDate,
    FROM EURUSD, 
    WHERE (Timestamps BETWEEN CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 12:00:00')::timestamp AND CONCAT(CustomDate, ' 15:30:00')::timestamp)
),
minMaxData AS (
  SELECT 
    CustomDate,
    MIN(Low) AS LowOfSession,
    MAX(High) AS HighOfSession
  FROM mySession
  GROUP BY CustomDate
),
getSpecificData AS (
  SELECT 
    m.CustomDate,
    m.HighOfSession AS HighMAX,
    s1.Timestamps AS HighMAXTime,      
    m.LowOfSession AS LowMIN,
    s2.Timestamps AS LowMINTime
  FROM minMaxData m 
    INNER JOIN mySession s1 ON m.CustomDate = s1.CustomDate AND m.HighOfSession = s1.High
    INNER JOIN mySession s2 ON m.CustomDate = s2.CustomDate AND m.LowOfSession = s2.Low
  ORDER BY m.CustomDate DESC
)
SELECT * FROM getSpecificData;
```

Comment: I tried this query but needed to change `ORDER BY CustomDate DESC` to `ORDER BY m.CustomDate DESC` in order to get a result. This result doesn't seem to add somehow, because I'm getting different timestamp values for LowMINTime and it does not group to a single day:


`│ 2023-01-31 │  1.0875 │ 2023-01-31 13:45:00 │ 1.08505 │ 2020-04-21 15:00:00 │`
`│ 2023-01-31 │  1.0875 │ 2023-01-31 13:45:00 │ 1.08505 │ 2015-04-07 12:55:00 │`
`│ 2023-01-31 │  1.0875 │ 2023-01-31 13:45:00 │ 1.08505 │ 2016-01-26 14:55:00 │`

Comment: Sorry, I've made a typo in JOIN condition for min time. The correct condition is `m.CustomDate = s2.CustomDate AND m.LowOfSession = s2.Low`. I've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: `2023-01-25 │ 1.09185 │ 2023-01-25 13:25:00 │  1.0894 │ 2023-01-25 12:05:00 
2023-01-24 │  1.0889 │ 2023-01-24 13:10:00 │ 1.08705 │ 2023-01-24 12:05:00
2023-01-24 │  1.0889 │ 2023-01-24 13:10:00 │ 1.08705 │ 2023-01-24 12:00:00
2023-01-23 │  1.0873 │ 2023-01-23 13:50:00 │ 1.08475 │ 2023-01-23 14:50:00
2023-01-20 │ 1.08585 │ 2023-01-20 14:45:00 │ 1.08295 │ 2023-01-20 12:00:00`
This is looking great. I get the good results but I also sometimes get multiple values per day:

Comment: I get multiple results per day because the Low or High can occur multiple times during the specific timeframe. Would it be possible to get only the first occurrence of High or Low, so that I only have a single unique day in the result query?